# best practice for tabbed layout in html

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui, tabs

I am studying html, css, javascript and jquery in a very basic level yet, and plan to use these technologies for personal projects, prototyping, etc. (NOT for professional web development/design).

I want to have a page with tabbed content, where each tab's content would come from a different html file (I want this because then I can manage each file individually).

I have seen CSS-only tabbed layout, JS-only tabbed layout, JQueryUI tabs, and any combination in between.

Since tabs are now commonplace in every site, I was wondering there would be a "right" way to do it, but I'm confused.

So, the question is: what is the "canonical" way to do a simple tabbed layout on a page, where each tab would be a "wrapper" to a separate html file to be diplayed inside?

Thanks for any answers!

Comment: This question doesn't really have a definitive answer.

Comment: @MetalFrog I can see it, but how do you think I could reformulate/relpace this question in order to get help on the topic, if possible?

Comment: @heltonbiker: You should ask a more specific question. Which step are you having trouble with? What have you tried?

Comment: Without using something like PHP (or another server-side language) to load those files in you probably need iframes. I think you need to re-evaluate what you're doing. Must they be separate files?

Comment: I appreciate the help received, but I also (now) vote for closing the question. I'll go with JQuery (don't like the dependencies, but...) and when a have a REAL question, I'll ask it. Thanks again.

Comment: Personally, I actually really understand your question. I remember myself being at that same point a couple of years ago, and not being able to find an answer. What's the best way? There's no definitive answer to that question, but you can show the different directions. There are so many trees, you just can't see the one you're looking for anymore...

Comment: there is nothing wrong with your question. the solution ive provided below should get you started. not sure why someone downvoted it, it works great for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, there are many ways to achieve your goal. Some people include a fully fledged framework like jQuery(UI) for this (which is in my opinion overkill, because you don't need such a gigantic framework for this), while others create a really simple script that's really hard to extend. Simply put, there are basically two ways to do this (with clearly many roads in between):

1. Use a server side scripting language. If you want to store every tab in a different HTML file, you will need a new request for every tab change anyways, so then it's not a big step to just managing the tabs using a server side scripting language, like PHP. You could just check for a $_GET variable and include a different file depending on the value. This is really easy. However, it's not possible to have animations;
2. This methods is, you could say, web 2.0-style; because you can have animations with this method. You should create a nice tabbed layout using CSS and then use Javascript for the tab switching. Yes, there are ways to do that using pure CSS, but that won't work in many browsers, so you'll have to use Javascript anyways.

   Then, there are two ways to load the actual content. You can use Javascript to load the content using an AJAX request when the user clicks a tab. However, this will mean that there could be some loading time on slower internet connections. Therefore, I personally prefer to load all content using a PHP include on the server side. That makes it really easy to manage the files, while still having the advantages of one file.

In this answer I've assumed you at least know a little bit about PHP, if that's not the case: please ask. Hope I helped. :)

Comment: That was the type of answer I wanted: pointng pros and cons of more than one method, and why. Also, you separated the layout problem from the content-loading problem. Thank you, even feeling the iminent closing of the question...

Comment: I wouldn't use PHP because I do not plan to open these pages via a webserver, but directly open the files on the browser via double-clicking.

Comment: @heltonbiker: No problem, I'm here to help. But indeed, if you're not using a webserver PHP isn't the way to go. Also, that means you won't have the loading time problems, so you should just go with AJAX. Good luck!

Comment: Now I'm having the problem related to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6605365/401828 Any suggestion?

Comment: The answer by Sayem Ahmed is right: you can't make an AJAX request to a page located on a different server. I don't know why the relative paths didn't work though... Maybe your operating system is case-sensitive?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can add is to ask yourself why you are using tabs in a particular instance. Is it to separate related content? Is it to navigate a site? Is it...etc?

The specific purpose of the tabs is what will typically lead you to the specific implementation that will work for it.

In other words, there is no *one* way to make tabs because there is no *one* use for tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Well in most of the sites, Tabbed content is not actually inside the tabs, Tabs are more like external links to different html pages so when you click on the tab you are moving to a new page altogether. Different technological implementation may have different advantages/disadvantages and I guess @St. Wolland's answer is the simplest to implement.
It doesn't matter how you create tab layout, at the end those will be linking to different files and your separation of logic will be maintained.